# Is there a convention for hotfix releases using git with the Feature Branch workflow?

Tags: git, feature-branch

When using the [Feature Branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-feature-branch) workflow with a small team (not [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow)), is there a convention for applying a hot fix to a release that was previously tagged on master?

For example:

1. v1.0.0 is released at a particular point in time, at which time a tag is created.
2. Developers continue to work on feature branches which are merged into master upon completion and review in preparation for a distant future release of v1.1.0.
3. Customers begin experiencing an issue, and it is deemed necessary to release a hotfix to v1.0.0 (call it v1.0.1) leaving out the progress made for v1.1.0.

With Gitflow, the branching structure is obvious, since master is only made up of the tagged releases -- branch from master, fix, merge fix into master, release and tag from master. With the Feature Branch workflow, I'd like to know how this is typically handled, preserving an easy-to-follow history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make the hotfix in a branch, tag it in the branch, and then merge the branch into `master`. That way, you still wind up with the fix available both for the hotfix release and for future releases, but the tag for the hotfix isn't part the first-parent chain of `master`.

Comment: Would this then require the hotfix branch to stick around forever to preserve the tag?

Comment: No, tags are not tied to branches, only commits.